# If statement is failing in C KDMF driver

Tags: c, windows, windows-kernel

I have this code, that is intended to find module base address in the process.

```
PVOID GetProcessModuleAdress(IN PEPROCESS __process,IN PUNICODE_STRING ModuleName)
{
    KAPC_STATE kapc;
    KeStackAttachProcess(__process, &kapc);
    DbgPrint("KeStackAttachProcess Success\n");
    PPEB pPeb = PsGetProcessPeb(__process);
    DbgPrint("PPEB Success");
    __int32 pid = PsGetProcessId(__process);
    DbgPrint("PID(In Module Addr) Success \n");
    DbgPrint("ModuleName is:"); DbgPrint(ModuleName); DbgPrint("\n");
    // Debug
    for (PLIST_ENTRY pListEntry = pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink; pListEntry != &pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList; pListEntry = pListEntry->Flink)
    {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Module: (%wZ)\n", pEntry->BaseDllName);
    }
    // End Debug
    for (PLIST_ENTRY pListEntry = pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink; pListEntry != &pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList; pListEntry = pListEntry->Flink)
    {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
        if (&pEntry->BaseDllName == ModuleName)
        {
            DbgPrint("\n Module found:");
            DbgPrint((PVOID)pEntry); DbgPrint("\n");
            KeUnstackDetachProcess(&kapc);
            return (PVOID)pEntry;
        }
    }

}
```

And the failing part is here:

```
        if (&pEntry->BaseDllName == ModuleName)
        {
            DbgPrint("\n Module found:");
            DbgPrint((PVOID)pEntry); DbgPrint("\n");
            KeUnstackDetachProcess(&kapc);
            return (PVOID)pEntry;
        }
```

Here I want to find the base address of process itself. And this code is working correnctly in term of finding modules inside the process. Output from windbg:

```
Find Process Success!
KeStackAttachProcess Success
PPEB SuccessPID(In Module Addr) Success 
ModuleName is:notepad.exe
Module: (notepad.exe)
Module: (ntdll.dll)
Module: (KERNEL32.DLL)
Module: (KERNELBASE.dll)
Module: (GDI32.dll)
Module: (win32u.dll)
Module: (gdi32full.dll)
Module: (msvcp_win.dll)
Module: (ucrtbase.dll)
Module: (USER32.dll)
Module: (msvcrt.dll)
Module: (combase.dll)
Module: (RPCRT4.dll)
Module: (bcryptPrimitives.dll)
Module: (shcore.dll)
Module: (advapi32.dll)
Module: (sechost.dll)
Module: (COMCTL32.dll)
Module: (IMM32.DLL)
Module: (kernel.appcore.dll)
Module: (uxtheme.dll)
Module: (clbcatq.dll)
Module: (MrmCoreR.dll)
Module: (MSCTF.dll)
Module: (OLEAUT32.dll)
Module: (windows.storage.dll)
Module: (profapi.dll)
Module: (powrprof.dll)
Module: (UMPDC.dll)
Module: (shlwapi.dll)
Module: (efswrt.dll)
Module: (MPR.dll)
Module: (wintypes.dll)
Module: (twinapi.appcore.dll)
Module: (RMCLIENT.dll)
Module: (SHELL32.dll)
Module: (cfgmgr32.dll)
Module: (cryptsp.dll)
Module: (oleacc.dll)
Module: (TextInputFramework.dll)
Module: (CoreUIComponents.dll)
Module: (CoreMessaging.dll)
Module: (ntmarta.dll)
Module: (iertutil.dll)
```

At the second loop, in first iteration it should be if("notepad.exe" == "notepad.exe"). But it does not go in "true" part of if. Maybe this is some kind of mismatch in null byte string ending?

Edit #1:
In "Debug" section in my code I get correct output:

```
Find Process Success!
KeStackAttachProcess Success
PPEB SuccessPID(In Module Addr) Success 
ModuleName is:notepad.exe
Module: (notepad.exe)
Module: (ntdll.dll)
Module: (KERNEL32.DLL)
Module: (KERNELBASE.dll)
Module: (GDI32.dll)
Module: (win32u.dll)
Module: (gdi32full.dll)
Module: (msvcp_win.dll)
Module: (ucrtbase.dll)
Module: (USER32.dll)
Module: (msvcrt.dll)
Module: (combase.dll)
Module: (RPCRT4.dll)
Module: (bcryptPrimitives.dll)
Module: (shcore.dll)
Module: (advapi32.dll)
Module: (sechost.dll)
Module: (COMCTL32.dll)
Module: (IMM32.DLL)
Module: (kernel.appcore.dll)
Module: (uxtheme.dll)
Module: (clbcatq.dll)
Module: (MrmCoreR.dll)
Module: (MSCTF.dll)
Module: (OLEAUT32.dll)
Module: (windows.storage.dll)
Module: (profapi.dll)
Module: (powrprof.dll)
Module: (UMPDC.dll)
Module: (shlwapi.dll)
Module: (efswrt.dll)
Module: (MPR.dll)
Module: (wintypes.dll)
Module: (twinapi.appcore.dll)
Module: (RMCLIENT.dll)
Module: (SHELL32.dll)
Module: (cfgmgr32.dll)
Module: (cryptsp.dll)
Module: (oleacc.dll)
Module: (TextInputFramework.dll)
Module: (CoreUIComponents.dll)
Module: (CoreMessaging.dll)
Module: (ntmarta.dll)
Module: (iertutil.dll)
```

But after that... strange things happen. Output code:

```
DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "First Argument: (%wZ)\n", &pEntry->BaseDllName);
        DbgPrint("\n");
        DbgPrintEx(0,0,"%d",strlen(&pEntry->BaseDllName));
        DbgPrint("\n");
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Second Argument: (%wZ)\n", ModuleName);
        DbgPrint("\n");
        DbgPrintEx(0,0,"%d",strlen(ModuleName));
        DbgPrint("\n");
```

And output:

```
First Argument: (notepad.exe)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (ntdll.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (KERNEL32.DLL)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (KERNELBASE.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (GDI32.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (win32u.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (gdi32full.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (msvcp_win.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (ucrtbase.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (USER32.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (msvcrt.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (combase.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (RPCRT4.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (bcryptPrimitives.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (shcore.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (advapi32.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (sechost.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (COMCTL32.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (IMM32.DLL)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (kernel.appcore.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (uxtheme.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (clbcatq.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (MrmCoreR.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (MSCTF.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (OLEAUT32.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (windows.storage.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (profapi.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (powrprof.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (UMPDC.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (shlwapi.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (efswrt.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (MPR.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (wintypes.dll)

1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (twinapi.appcore.dll)
```

Constant lengths in strlen are very strange

Edit #3
Changed if statement to this function, but still no luck

```
if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&pEntry->BaseDllName,&ModuleName,0))
        {
            DbgPrint("\n Module found:");
            DbgPrint((PVOID)pEntry); DbgPrint("\n");
            KeUnstackDetachProcess(&kapc);
            return (PVOID)pEntry;
        }
```

Comment: Are you shure that pEntry value is not null?

Comment: Well... it is getting the dll names. So I suppose that no. After trying to print it out in windbg I got: `ì1. Weird value, but it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (&pEntry->BaseDllName == ModuleName)
```

You are comparing string pointers, not the string values.

Try to use strcmp() like below:

```
if (strcmp(&pEntry->BaseDllName, ModuleName) == 0)
```

Comment: That is not getting through too. Looping through but not finding anything

Comment: What means: "not finding"? The if-condition is false?

Comment: Take a look for your thesis, that ("notepad.exe" == "notepad.exe") is true. NOPE: this is comparison of string pointers, not string values. Both strings can have identical value, but can be located at different adresses, and this condition will be false.

Comment: Yes. It is going to "false" in if always

Comment: I suppose that strcmp is using string values, not addresses.

Comment: If you use strcmp() instead of strict comparison, the values will be compared. It means strcmp("notepad.exe", "notepad.exe") will return 0 (it means: identical), what is expected. The strict comparison works in other languages, like c#, but not in c :)

Comment: Now I am using: 
if (strcmp(&pEntry->BaseDllName, ModuleName) == 0)
But it keep setting if to false :(

Comment: What OS? Windows? So it can be string encoding problem too... Try to add DbgPrintEx() showing both strings, placed before your 'if'.

Comment: Yes. It is windows 10. Printed out both arguments before if: First Argument: (notepad.exe)
Second Argument: (notepad.exe)

Comment: Ok, add to DbgPrintEx() lenghth too (hint: 'strlen()'). Maybe one of strings contains spaces or other invisible characters at the beginning/end.

Comment: After some digging in it, I found some strange thing. Using the: DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "(%wZ)\n", pEntry->BaseDllName); And for modulename, I get very similar, but not the same outputs. For BaseDllName I get - (notepad.exe) But for modulename - (notepad.exe. Without the one parenthesis.
And strlen() generates the ? or & things

Comment: strlen() returns the string length as integer, so for printing the int value in DbgPrintEx() you must use format "%d".

Comment: At this point, I have almost lost the clue, what is happening here. Seems like, something wrong is with ModuleName, in the function call. ```GetProcessModuleAdress(__process, "notepad.exe");```
Strlen gives the constant ints 1 and 11. It does not matter, what module is found. In the first debug outputs, it shows correctly the modulename, but in second, it is just (
Example:
```
1
Second Argument: (
11
First Argument: (KERNEL32.DLL)
```

Comment: Would you like to show your code with these diagnostics entries? Maybe not here, rather simply edit/update your question - it will be easier to comment more ;)

Comment: Ooooo... :) Ok, it seems that the first string (&pEntry->BaseDllName) is encoded as unicode or utf-8, so it is properly displayed using format "%wZ", but strlen() function shows improper len (it is not able to calculate length of unicode/utf encoded strings), but the second string (ModuleName) is encoded as ASCII, so strlen() shows proper size, but the format "%wZ" not allows to display ASCII encoded string. For confirmation change the format string in displaying the second string, it means change it to 'DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Second Argument: (%s)\n", ModuleName);' and show the results :)

Comment: Thank you :) I am on one step forward now. Now it outputs first and second arguments correctly. But strlen remains the same :(

Comment: Of course. It means the both strings are encoded differently, in different way. So, it is not possible to compare them - rather you must transcode one of them to the encoding used by the second one, then compare them, using proper function (strcmp() works only on ASCII encoded strings, there are different functions related to wide-char strings, like utf/unicode encoded). Read some about character encoding in C ;), and maybe consider to get ModuleName encoded like the second string is.

Comment: Maybe you know some example to do it? :)

Comment: Yes, I know. But maybe try to do it yourself? ;) I provided all hints, needed for finding things in google :)

Comment: Ok. From structs, I found that BaseDllName is UNICODE_STRING and ModuleName is PUNICODE_STRING. So I found the function: RtlEqualUnicodeString();. Which should say, if they are equal or not. And from Edit#3 it is not working too :( Have tried ModuleName with and without pointer.

Comment: So use wcscmp(), and check, why ModuleName is encoded as ASCII ,not UNICODE. If ModuleName is taken from string literal (like: "notepad.exe"), try to prefix the string literal using 'L' (like L"notepad.exe"). Of course you must include additional headers: wchar.h (and probably locale.h).